# how to mount /var/log/ to separate partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, fstab

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new Server and I need to mount `/var/log` to a separate partition. I created a new partiton with `ext4` and mounting it manually works fine.
The server does not boot if I mount `/var/log` during boot via `fstab`.

```
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:52:54 server kernel: [ 2126.966538] EXT4-fs (nvme2n1p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping Session 1 of user root.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping Session 5 of user USERNAME.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping Availability of block devices...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping Session 3 of user root.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping The PHP 5.6 FastCGI Process Manager...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping D-Bus System Message Bus...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping The PHP 7.1 FastCGI Process Manager...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping Unattended Upgrades Shutdown...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping Deferred execution scheduler...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters...
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server blkdeactivate[13934]: Deactivating block devices:
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopped Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
/var/log/syslog:Nov 21 18:53:18 server systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.

/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log:2019-11-21 18:53:18,394 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgradesonly if it is running
```

`/dev/nvme2n1p1` would be the target partition.
What is the correct way to mount a separate `/var/log` partition on boot?

My `fstab`:

```
/dev/md/0 / ext4 noatime 0 1
#/dev/nvme2n1p1 /var/log ext4 noatime 0 2
/dev/md/1 /home ext4 noatime 0 2
/dev/md/2 /tmp ext4 noatime 0 2
/dev/md/3 /var/www ext4 noatime 0 2
/dev/nvme2n1p2 /var/backup ext4 noatime 0 2
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
```

Comment: I don't understand this "But the server hangs on reboot as long as i activated the /var/log partition in the fstab file" part of your question!

Comment: What's the entry on `fstab`?

Comment: Mounting `/var/log` to a different partitions means that logging will be unavailable until that partition is mounted. On my system mounts dont' happen until several seconds into the boot process. Type `journalctl -b 0 -o short-monotonic`, search for `mount` and see what you'll miss.

Comment: sorry for beeing unclear and for my english, i updated my question.

It's a remote server. Running journalctl -b 0 -o short-monotonic in the rescue system, i get Failed to get boot id: No such file or directory

Comment: thanks for the tips, i made two errors:
first one was stupid typo and i did no proper chroot. i found the error via journalctl

Comment: @PatientNr0 Can you please post an answer to your own question how you solved this?  Then leave a comment [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote!  **0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby Done it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use the UUIDs in fstab. Without them it swapped nvme1n1p1 with nvme2n1p1 and vice versa every start so the partition was always busy and couldn't be mounted. I've never seen such a behavior before. I made countless reboots with the UUIDs and now it works just fine

Comment: As promised!  **;-)** *Sorry for late reply: been busy...*